# HDF5: alias for data-keys in caffe

Tags: python, hdf5, caffe, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to load HDF5 data for my caffe-net as input data. So far I can create those hdf5-databases and the list file. I also read the simple example in https://ceciliavision.wordpress.com/2016/03/21/caffe-hdf5-layer/. There is stated that the dataset keys are also the names of the data-layer in caffe. But what I want is a to give them kind of aliases in caffe, is that possible? The reason is that I have two hdf5-DB with the same dataset-structure inside, so also the same dataset-keys. Is there a name-clash if I load both hdf5-DB in the same net and if so can I change the names without changing the hdf5-DB itself?
Thanks for help!

Comment: that's a pickle... if you open the HDF5 in python and wrap the hdf read as a python layer...

Comment: I don't understand, caffe has a hdf5 layer or do you mean I need an extra python layer for wrapping the load of the hdf5-DB?

Comment: what I meant is that AFAIK caffe does not have this "aliasing" property built into `"HDF5Data"` layer, and do get this functionality one would need to use a python layer as a wrapper...

Comment: Could you give an example how to write such a python layer for reading input HDF5-DB?